# why django model date filter generates query with a day before

Tags: python, django, date

```
import datetime
d = datetimte.datetime.today()
print d
2015-01-02 03:59:48.392104
print CourseDay.objects.filter(date__exact=d).query

SELECT `website_courseday`.`id`, `website_courseday`.`date`,
`website_courseday`.`presentation_id` FROM `website_courseday` 
 WHERE `website_courseday`.`date` = 2015-01-01 22:29:48
```

why it generate the date a day before the value ?

I am using django 1.4.10, and mysql as db server.

Comment: Looks like a timezone problem -- specifically, the difference of exactly 5.5 hours suggests it's **India**'s timezone (few timezones are off a non-integer number of hours from UTC, but India's is one, and 5.5 is its exact offset).  Django seems to be normalizing the datetime to UTC.  You can use `pytz` to undo that -- or just use `datetime.date.today()` if, as it appears, **that** (a `date`, not a `datetime`), is what you want.

Comment: I set USE_TZ = False, is that okey ?

Comment: `USE_TZ = False`, which is also the default, doesn't seem to be working for you -- not sure when it was implemented, you may need a more recent Django release than 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be confusing `datetime` objects with `date` objects.

(I'm assuming that the `date` field of `CourseDay` is a `DateField`, since an `__exact` query doesn't make much sense for a `DateTimeField`.)

If all you care about is the local time (which seems to be the case if you have `USE_TZ=False`), the solution is simple:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date.today()  # note the difference
CourseDay.objects.filter(date__exact=d)  # should work as you expect
```

Comment: CouseDay.date is DateTimeField. now I am using date__range to filter. and its working fine.